# Check if Ninject binding is InRequestScope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

If I get the bindings for an interface type from a specific Ninject kernel instance, is there a way to verify what type of binding it is (i.e.: `InSingletonScope()`, `InRequestScope()`)?

(Simplified) example:

```
IKernel kernel = NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel();
var binding = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IService)).FirstOrDefault();

var bindingType = binding...??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.InRequestScope()` itself calls: `IBindingSyntax.InScope(Func<IContext, object> scope);`

The ScopeCallback (`Func<IContext, object> scope`) can be retrieved by:

```
 kernel
     .GetBindings(typeof(IService))
     .Single()
     .ScopeCallback
```

But comparing Func's not really a nice thing. It feels very hackish but we can do the following to retrieve the request scope callback to compare:

```
private Func<IContext, object> RetrieveInRequestScopeCallback()
{
    using (var kernel = new StandardKernel())
    {
        kernel.Bind<object>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        return kernel.GetBindings(typeof(object)).Single().ScopeCallback;
    }
}
```

now a unit test like the following will pass:

```
[Fact]
public void Foo()
{
    Func<IContext, object> inRequestScopeCallback = RetrieveInRequestScopeCallback();

    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<string>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

    IBinding binding = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(string)).Single();
    binding.ScopeCallback.Should().Be(inRequestScopeCallback);
}
```

(i've used [FluentAssertions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/) and [xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/2.0.0-beta4-build2738))

But as i've said this is hackish. Why do you want to verify the bindings? I suggest it would be better to invest that time into creating automated integration / system tests. That's usually the way to go with DI containers: you don't unit test whether you've configured them correctly, you test this with integration and system tests.

Comment: I wanted to make sure that a class that has disposable dependencies is itself bound `InRequestScope()` to avoid disposable dependencies having a lifetime longer that a single request. It is my understanding that when, for instance, a type with an `InSingletonScope()` binding has a dependency with an `InRequestScope()` binding, this dependency will indeed not get disposed at the end of the request (due to the class which has this dependency living on). I wanted to write a test to make sure a developer wouldn't forget this causing unexpected behaviour. If there's another way, let me know.

Comment: @bump you are looking for [captive dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). [Castle](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) and [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) both have detection mechanisms built in.

Comment: yes @qujck is right. If it's really important to you i would either switch to one of the frameworks he mentioned or create an according pull request. Sadly enough i think that Ninject pull requests will take a very long time to go through / be accepted.

Comment: On the other hand eliminating captive dependencies does not make sure that `.Dispose()` is actually called *and* implemented correctly. If you can unit test it, then you can also spec-test it... and if you do so then captive-dependency detection is obsolete.

Comment: Switching frameworks isn't an option right now, but this is good to know when starting another project. I'm not familiar with the term spec-test, would you have a link providing some more info?

Comment: @bump well i'm using the term *spec test* rather liberally. With unit-test lots of people immediately think of "testing a single class and mocking/faking/stubbing all dependencies". With a spec-test i mean a composition of classes into a sensible "module" or "component", maybe even the entire system. So it's some kind of "integration" test. However the issue with these is that's it's a lot of tedious work: since the captive dependency could be caused by any number of objects, you'd have get high-coverage branch testing.

Comment: When the container (or some other tool) can detect captive dependencies, that can be solved generically - much easier. However, a "spec" test usually tests much more than only captive dependencies...